# Keystroke duplicating in data grid

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

The issue that I am experiencing is easy to reproduce.

When attempting to update the data of a row using the data tab of SQL Developer the cell will receive the first letter twice.

This happens "intermittently"; ~50% of the time when I go to enter fresh data into the cell.

This is most noticeable when you have ~10 columns of Y/N flags and want to simply <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> and end up with `Y` `YY` `YY` and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> rolls you another ~50% chance of fixing it. See image at bottom of question.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Environment specs:

```
Windows 7 x64
SQL Developer 4.1.5.21.78
C:\Program Files\Oracle\SQL Developer\4.1.5.21.78\jdk\jre\release | JAVA_VERSION = 1.8.0_102
```

I've been using the latest versions for over 3 years now and this issue has been persistent in all of the versions.

---

**Example:**

[image: SQL Developer double-keystroke issue]

Comment: @thatjeffsmith may help for this issue.

Comment: I used to see this when the console would echo the keypresses as well as emit them on screen, so you'd see your keypress outputted back to you, as well as the effect of the keypress. This might be the problem here, but I'm running on guesswork.

Comment: @RandolphWest I am not sure I fully understand what I need to look for. Please see the image I've added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know. It was a guess. Look in the preferences maybe.

Comment: Is this a new installation of SQL developer?

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanPadhi This one (4.1.5.21.78), no. I received a new laptop about 2 months ago and my new 4.1.3.20.78 install was doing this as well. 3 years ago I did a fresh Windows install and this was occurring on that version also.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Okay. I have posted a solution. I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: @BibhutiBhusanPadhi I just saw that answer come through. I will try it out when I have some time today. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following possible solution:
1. Go to the following directory in c:\ drive:

```
C:\Users\<your_user_id>\AppData\Roaming\
```

2. There you will find folder(s) named `SQL Developer`and`sqldeveloper`
3. Rename those folders (whose name is like SQL developer and sqldeveloper) to something like SQL Developer1 and sqldeveloper1 respectively or as you like.
4. Restart SQL Developer application.

Note: After performing the above operations  all your Connections data will get erased. So, you might need to first export all your connections into an .xml file.

Hope this solves your problem !!

Comment: tried that, it didn't work, thanks anyway